# Deploy Jenkins build to Sonatype Nexus

Tags: php, jenkins, gitlab, nexus, sonatype

I have already integrated `sonar-cube`,`Jenkins` and `git lab`.Is there a way to add the `Jenkins` build result (my all projects are `php Angular`) to the `Sonatype Nexus` repository (`Sonatype Nexus` already installed)?

Answer (score 0):

Run a shell command after building to pack your project as tar.gz and upload it to a nexus server. The following example is for nexus 2.*. You will have to check the curl sintax for Nexus 3. It will run composer, zip the release with specific vendors without forcing you to have to run composer install on your client environment. Note the variables you will have to add.

Make sure you always do a clean install by checking out the c

```
if [ -f composer.json ]; then composer install; fi;
tar -zcvf ../`echo $JOB_NAME-$RELEASE.tar.gz | sed -e s/'- Release'/''/g  | sed -e s/'\-\-'/'\-'/g |  tr -d ' ' ` ./
mv ../`echo $JOB_NAME-$RELEASE.tar.gz | sed -e s/'- Release'/''/g  | sed -e s/'\-\-'/'\-'/g |  tr -d ' ' ` ./
curl -v \
    -F r=releases \
    -F g=com.acme \
    -F a=widget \
    -F v=$RELEASE \
    -F p=tar.gz \
    -F file=@./`echo $JOB_NAME-$RELEASE.tar.gz | sed -e s/'- Release'/''/g  | sed -e s/'\-\-'/'\-'/g |  tr -d ' ' ` \
-u $USER_LOGIN:$USER_PASSWORD \
http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/service/\local/repositories/php/content`echo $JOB_NAME-$RELEASE.tar.gz | sed -e s/'- Release'/''/g  | sed -e s/'\-\-'/'\-'/g |  tr -d ' ' `
rm -f `echo $JOB_NAME-$RELEASE.tar.gz | sed -e s/'- Release'/''/g  | sed -e s/'\-\-'/'\-'/g |  tr -d ' ' `
```